# Console.Beep not working on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make a WPF application that will play a series of musical notes. To play each note, I am using the `Console.Beep(frequency, duration)` function. However, the function is not making a sound. It's running on a worker thread. It works perfectly well on a console application. Most other posts say either to use `Console.Beep`, or `SystemSounds.Beep.Play`, which doesn't allow for a change in sound.

Comment: Please post the code which you tried.,

Comment: Are you using a 64 bit OS?

Comment: Try this link which similar to your question. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/141617/WPF-Midi-Band

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue on Windows 8.1 (x64). I have tried `Console.Beep(5000, 1000)`, `Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Console.Beep(5000, 1000))`, and `new Thread(() => Console.Beep(5000, 1000)).Start()`. All seem to work fine. You have your speakers on, right?